# How to format this json

Tags: javascript, json, format

I'm writing some JSON for a temporary table view on a website. Never written JSON before so would really appreciate some help.

I need to show lists of crew members split into sets of 18 per year which are then split into 2 sets of 9 ech with 4 properties.

The hierarchy would look something like this:

- 2013

  - Result
  - Blue boat

    - position, name, college, weight
    - (+8 more)
  - Isis (reserve boat)
- 2012
- 2011
- (...since 1829)

This is my first attempt at writing/formatting JSON so please only comment if you're being helpful or constructive.

**JSON**

```
{
"crews": [{
    "items": [
    {
        "year"      :   "2013",
        "boat"      :   "Blue",
        "position"  :   "1",
        "name"      :   "Patrick Close",
        "college"   :   "Pembroke",
        "weight"    :   "14st 2lbs"
    }, {
        "year"      :   "2013",
        "boat"      :   "Blue",
        "position"  :   "2",
        "name"      :   "Geordie Macleod",
        "college"   :   "Christ Church",
        "weight"    :   "13st 10lbs"
    }, {
        "year"      :   "2013",
        "boat"      :   "Isis",
        "position"  :   "1",
        "name"      :   "Iain Mandale",
        "college"   :   "Mansfield",
        "weight"    :   "11st 11lbs"
    }, {
        "year"      :   "2013",
        "boat"      :   "Isis",
        "position"  :   "2",
        "name"      :   "Nichola Hazell",
        "college"   :   "Christ Church",
        "weight"    :   "14st 9lbs"
    }]
}
}
```

**Is this better?**

```
{
"crews": [
    {
        "year": [
            {
                "2013": [
                    {
                        "boat": [
                            {
                                "Blue": [
                                    {
                                        "boat"      :   "Blue",
                                        "position"  :   "1",
                                        "name"      :   "Patrick Close",
                                        "college"   :   "Pembroke",
                                        "weight"    :   "14st 2lbs"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "boat"      :   "Blue",
                                        "position"  :   "2",
                                        "name"      :   "Geordie Macleod",
                                        "college"   :   "Christ Church",
                                        "weight"    :   "13st 10lbs"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Isis": [
                                    {
                                        "boat"      :   "Isis",
                                        "position"  :   "1",
                                        "name"      :   "Iain Mandale",
                                        "college"   :   "Mansfield",
                                        "weight"    :   "11st 11lbs"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "year"      :   "2013",
                                        "boat"      :   "Isis",
                                        "position"  :   "2",
                                        "name"      :   "Nichola Hazell",
                                        "college"   :   "Christ Church",
                                        "weight"    :   "14st 9lbs"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: You are missing one closing square bracket. I assume that you need to put it right before the last closing curly bracket.

Comment: If you are doing lots of things like this I would recommend you to use a tempting library like [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) or [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/).

Comment: Your JSON is much better now.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey Thanks, could you explain what exactly makes it 'better', and how? Would help me understand it.

Comment: The structure. Now it's easier to loop over. It is easier to use with an MV* framework or Templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON isn't valid. You can test it at [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/), fixed:

```
{
    "crews": [
        {
            "items": [
                {
                    "year": "2013",
                    "boat": "Blue",
                    "position": "1",
                    "name": "Patrick Close",
                    "college": "Pembroke",
                    "weight": "14st 2lbs"
                },
                {
                    "year": "2013",
                    "boat": "Blue",
                    "position": "2",
                    "name": "Geordie Macleod",
                    "college": "Christ Church",
                    "weight": "13st 10lbs"
                },
                {
                    "year": "2013",
                    "boat": "Isis",
                    "position": "1",
                    "name": "Iain Mandale",
                    "college": "Mansfield",
                    "weight": "11st 11lbs"
                },
                {
                    "year": "2013",
                    "boat": "Isis",
                    "position": "2",
                    "name": "Nichola Hazell",
                    "college": "Christ Church",
                    "weight": "14st 9lbs"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to alter the output show how you generate this and an example of what you want it to look like.

Comment: Thanks, think I've come up with a better solution (see updated question). Any thoughts?